# Defining dynamic ranges in vba

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic-values

How do I specify the cell in the column next to the very last cell with data in a spreadsheet e.g. if I have data in

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
```

How do I dynamically define

```
Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRow, n_lastColumn))
```

In a function such that `n_lastColumn` refers to the next column after `lastColumn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).offset(,1)`

or

`Range("A1").currentregion.offset(,1)`

Comment: Note that `CurrentRegion` stops at empty lines/columns which might lead to  undesired behavior if you have sparse data.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `UsedRange` property that's available on a `Worksheet` object.

But note that that gives you a *watermark* used range as opposed to the currently used range; i.e. if you write a value in a cell then remove it, that still comprises the `UsedRange`.

Comment: It seems to update the `UsedRange` when you use it in a macro. After a bit of testing I found it to be unreliable though. At some point it would adjust the column but not the row and kept including cells that were never filled.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub find_last()

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim WS as Worksheet

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")


    LastRow = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=WS.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False).row
    LastCol = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=WS.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False).Column


    WS.Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1) = "MyData"

end sub
```